# PSDH and SCP to transfer files

Tags: networking, ssh, scp

How can I use PDSH and SCP to transfer file to my servers (over 200 of them coming from a text file - ips)

Also how can I automate this? Have people written scripts for this? Examples?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean parallel-ssh (`apt-get install pssh` on Debian), you can do this quite simply this way.

```
parallel-scp -h ips localfile /remote/path/file
```

If you meant `pdcp`, which is part of the `pdsh` package, I would pass on it - I just gave it a try and it would seem it requires `pdcp` to be present on the remote host, unlike `parallel-scp`. So I would stick to the former if you can - but if you must you can try this:

```
hosts=`cat ips | tr '\n' ','`
pdcp -R ssh -w $hosts localfile remotefile
```

This assumes `ips` has a host per line. It reads it and replaces the newlines by commas, thus creating a list in the format expected by `pdcp`. You can skip this step if you already have a comma-separated list of course.